# Any difference betweenn posts and pages for one page?

Tags: posts, get-posts, pages

I've been checking out WordPress but I'm having some trouble figuring out what I should use to get the text from WordPress on my site. Posts or pages. I'm making a one-page website. I know how to get text from posts but not from pages.

Can you help me out with how I can get pages with a loop and if I should use a post or page?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Post and page behave in same way. The only exceptions of page is that it's doesn't support taxonomies like- category and tags but it's have hierarchy

Comment: That is definitely not the only difference between pages and posts! Neither in function or in usage. i.e. posts often contain timestamped information "Posted by Jim of 11/11/2011" ect. while pages generally don't. They COULD either have either functionality, but it is a matter of practice that most themes by default do not do this. There are hundreds of other differences!

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a one-page website, and you are going to use WordPress, create a WordPress "Page", and put your content in it. Then in the Dashboard > Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays, select "A static page", and choose the page you created.

To create a Wordpress "Loop" within a page, you would normally use PHP to modify a page template [very different from a page], in a theme. Or use PHP to create a shortcode in a plugin that can be used in any theme. It is confusing though what you mean by: "a one-page website, and including a loop." That doesn't really make sense. A loop generally is used to sort through multiple pages and posts, via a query. I've never seen a one page Wordpress site that uses a loop. What would you be looping through?

You can also set your front page to actually be a loop of posts in most themes. Just go to the Dashboard > Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays, select "Your latest posts".